# SKAction.playSoundFileNamed -- how to set its volume between 0.0 - 1.0

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, skaction

Please only swift code answers....

```
var sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    playSound(sound)
    //call playSound method when you want
}

func playSound(sound : SKAction)
{
    runAction(sound)
}
```

Code above is what i need help on to set sounds volume.  I want change the volume level on my sound but have not found my answer anywhere.  I have also tried the ChangeVolume(to:) function but it also didn't seem to work.  Any one of you that can help me solve this problem i would be thankful :).  My reason for using an Skaction to play my sound is because when i use this method below my game lags when the sounds plays, but if you can help prevent its lag that code would be great aswell. :) thank you.

```
func playAudio() {
        do {
            if let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BOUN'Z_Firt_Level", ofType: "mp3") {
                let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: bundle)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                try audioPlayerTwo = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound as URL)
                audioPlayerTwo.numberOfLoops = -1
                audioPlayerTwo.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayerTwo.play()
                audioPlayerTwo.volume = 0.5
            }
        } catch {
//            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One general approach to such deadlocks is to actually change the volume of the sound file using a sound editor. So you would have the same sound named differently for different volumes/purpose.